# Convergence of quadrature for non-smooth integrands

Tags: numerical-methods

Standard convergence estimates for quadrature formulas $(w_i,x_x)_{i = 1}^n$ are of the form
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \, f(x_i)\right| \leq C (b - a)^{p+1} \max_{x \in (a,b)} |f^{(p)}(x)|,
$$
see e.g.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis,
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpsons_rule#Error.

What if the function is not $p$ times continuously differentiable, but only $p'<p$? Can I then assume
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i \, f(x_i)\right| \leq C (b - a)^{p'+1} \max_{x \in (a,b)} |f^{(p')}(x)|,
$$
or is there any other theory available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is good theory available for this case, too. A good paper to start with is

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/An_Elementary_Proof30705.pdf

You may also be interested in doing an asymptotic error analysis of your integrals, in order to obtain reliable and accurate error *estimates* as a priori error bounds can be *very* pessimistic. One reliable technique is Richardson extrapolation.